# Quartz Scheduler in AnnotationConfigApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, applicationcontext

I have schedules few jobs using Quartz Scheduler (Using JobDetailFactoryBean) with Spring. Now i achieved this by spring configuration via XmlApplicationContext and i have to change this same to AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.So how can i implement this cronjob in AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.
This is the sample job

```
<bean id="simpleJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
        <property name="jobClass">
            <value>com.scheduling.SimpleJob</value>
        </property>
        <property name="jobDataAsMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="anotherBean">
                    <ref bean="anotherBean" />
                </entry>                
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
        <property name="jobDetail">
            <ref bean="simpleJob" />
        </property>
        <property name="cronExpression">
            <value>0 55 23 * * ?</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="triggers">      
            <list>      
                <ref bean="simpleTrigger" />            
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig
{
  @Scheduled(cron="0 55 23 * * ?")
  public void doSomething() {
      // something that should execute every night at 23:55
  }
}
```

[See here for more details](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html).